# Schrodinger doesn't open in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

I have installed a software package named Schrodinger in Ubuntu 22.04. I get icons of this package, but when I want to run one of this package and click its icon I get an error message and it does not open. During the installation process I get this warning: `skipping tendency verification`.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be fine. The script is configured not to verify dependencies by default. If you face any error when running the program, then use the support link given in the screenshot above.

Comment: Do you get any error message when you run the installed program (not the installation script) from terminal?